# How to generate dart doc for every package in project

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to generate dart documentation for all packages in my project. My structure is like this:

```
my_app
- lib/
-- main.dart
- packages/
-- feature_name/
--- feature_name.dart
```

and I would like to have a single dartdoc which lists all libraries in lib and all in packages.

The "includeExternal" flag in dartdoc_options.yaml does not work for this, as you have to specify every file that should be included and a barrelfile does not seem to work atm.

Comment: You could use [melos](https://melos.invertase.dev/) for that. You would create a script `doc` (for example) and run `melos run doc`

Comment: (how) would that automatically merge the documentation of all packages?